# Using Spring @Cacheable with @PostFilter

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-security, spring-cache

I'm attempting to use both the `@Cacheable` and `@PostFilter` annotations in Spring. The desired behavior is that the application will cache the full, unfiltered listed of Segments (it's a very small and very frequently referenced list so performance is the desire), but that a User will only have access to certain Segments based on their roles.

I started out with both `@Cacheable` and `@PostFilter` on a single method, but when that wasn't working I broke them out into two separate classes so I could have one annotation on each method. However, it seems to behave the same either way I do it, which is to say when User A hits the service for the first time they get their correct filtered list, then when User B hits the service next they get NO results because the cache is only storing User A's filtered results, and User B does not have access to any of them. (So the PostFilter still runs, but the Cache seems to be storing the filtered list, not the full list.)

So here's the relevant code:

**configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class BcmsSecurityAutoConfiguration { 

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
                new ConcurrentMapCache("bcmsSegRoles"),
                new ConcurrentMapCache("bcmsSegments")
        ));
        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class ScopeService {

    private final ScopeRepository scopeRepository;

    public ScopeService(final ScopeRepository scopeRepository) {
        this.scopeRepository = scopeRepository;
    }

    // Filters the list of segments based on User Roles. User will have 1 role for each segment they have access to, and then it's just a simple equality check between the role and the Segment model.
    @PostFilter(value = "@bcmsSecurityService.canAccessSegment( principal, filterObject )")
    public List<BusinessSegment> getSegments() {
        List<BusinessSegment> segments = scopeRepository.getSegments();
        return segments; // Debugging shows 4 results for User A (post-filtered to 1), and 1 result for User B (post-filtered to 0)
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public class ScopeRepository {
    private final ScopeDao scopeDao; // This is a MyBatis interface.

    public ScopeRepository(final ScopeDao scopeDao) {
        this.scopeDao = scopeDao;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "bcmsSegments")
    public List<BusinessSegment> getSegments() {
        List<BusinessSegment> segments = scopeDao.getSegments(); // Simple SELECT * FROM TABLE; Works as expected.
        return segments; // Shows 4 results for User A, breakpoint not hit for User B cache takes over.
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the Cache seems to be storing the result of the Service method *after* the filter runs, rather than storing the full result set at the Repository level as I'm expecting it should? Or have another way to achieve my desired behavior?

Bonus points if you know how I could gracefully achieve both caching and filtering on the same method in the Service. I only built the superfluous Repository because I thought splitting the methods would resolve the caching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the contents of Spring caches are mutable, and the `@PostFilter` annotation modifies the returned list, it does not filter into a new one.

So when @PostFilter ran after my Service method call above it was actually removing items from the list stored in the Cache, so the second request only had 1 result to start with, and the third would have zero.

My solution was to modify the Service to `return new ArrayList<>(scopeRepo.getSegments());` so that PostFilter wasn't changing the cached list.

(NOTE, that's not a deep clone of course, so if someone modified a Segment model upstream from the Service it would likely change in the model in the cache as well. So this may not be the best solution, but it works for my personal use case.)

I can't believe Spring Caches are mutable...